# Algolia redirect to search results

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, vue.js, algolia

I'm having problem with redirecting search results to page that I want to display results. Want to have search bar in header so that my results are displayed on results page or something similar. All was done by tutorial (Laracasts), still learning javascript, so I'm a bit stuck here.. Some help would be great!

index.blade.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.1/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: 'body',

        data: {
            query: '',
            users: []
        },

        ready: function () {
            this.client = algoliasearch('', '');
            this.index = this.client.initIndex('test_drive_contacts');


            $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                        source: this.index.ttAdapter(),
                        displayKey: 'firstname',
                        templates: {
                            suggestion: function (hit) {
                                return '<div>' +
                                        '<h4 class="high">' + hit._highlightResult.firstname.value + '</h4>' +
                                        '<h5 class="high">' + hit._highlightResult.company.value + '</h5>'
                                        + '</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .on('typeahead:select', function (e, suggestion) {
                        this.query = suggestion.firstname;
                    }.bind(this));
        },


        methods: {
            search: function () {
                this.index.search(this.query, function (error, results) {
                    this.users = results.hits;
                }.bind(this));
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

This is the search input:

```
<input id="typeahead" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="query"
                                   v-on="keyup: search | key 'enter'">

<article v-repeat="user: users">
    <h2>@{{ user.firstname }}</h2>
    <h4>@{{ user.company }}</h4
</article>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Would you mind clarifying it?

Comment: When I type in search query, how do I redirect so that results are shown in     page that I want. Now it displays under my search input. Don't know how to redirect results on let's call it "results page". Hope I explained it better now..

Comment: I'm still unsure what you you're asking help for. Redirecting in JavaScript is as easy as doing `window.location = url`. Your code already uses the `typeahead:select` event, which is where you'd want to redirect.

Comment: How do I write this? That is my problem, I don't know syntax very well.. I just want to display results in page not under input search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting users to a page in JavaScript is as easy as doing

```
window.location = 'your_url_here'
```

If you're just looking to redirect to a `/search?q=query` page when the user types <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that's as easy as wrapping the input you're using inside a form.

```
<form action="/search" method="GET">
  <input type="search" id="your-input" name="q" />
</form>
```

If you want to redirect to an item page, the `typeahead:select` event gives you the selected option :

```
$('#your-input')
  .typeahead(/* ... */)
  .on('typeahead:select', function (e, suggestion) {
    window.location = suggestion.url;
  });
```