# pass Algolia id attribute instead of Name Atributre in a post request on Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, typeahead.js, algolia

Using the Javascript, Vue.js and Typeahead.js way shown by Jeffery Way and Algolia docs to index json objects from the Algolia platform.

Currently when i search for the result i require and hit the submit button, It is passing the name attribute through in the post request.

How is it possible to pass the name and the id attribute or if nescessery just the ID arrtibute would work.

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el: 'body', 
    data: {     
    query: '',
    users: []       
    },  
ready: function(){
this.client = algoliasearch("MYID", "MYAPI");
this.index = this.client.initIndex('dev_category_list');
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {   
    source: this.index.ttAdapter(),
    displayKey: 'name'
});
},
  methods: {
    search: function(){
        if (this.query.length < 3) return;
    this.index.search(this.query, function(error, results){
    this.users = results.hits;
    }.bind(this));
    }     
}  
})
</script>
```

As a total newcomer the laravel, vuejs and javascript its somewhat difficult to get to grips with the syntax and phrases used when explaining the instructons within the docs so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My indexed objects look like so:

```
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "My Product 3",
  "value": "3",
  "alternative_name": "Prod 3",
  "objectID": "3"
}
```

Im hoping to pass the value of ID or objectID along with the name attribute in a post request once the user selects the given result from the algolia drop down menu and hits the submit, just the ID would work as mentioned above if its not possible.

Thanks.

---

**--- Update referencing Jerska: ---**

Ok so after playing around as a newbie for a little bit i seem to have it working, Im not exactly sure how secure this is or how reliable one would say, Hopefully im not a million miles off from where i need to be. Be good to see what your personal and professional thoughts are.

```
.on('typeahead:select', function (e, suggestion) {
   $('#typeahead').change(function() {
    var val = suggestion.id;
    $('#st').val(val);
});
```

I have created a hidden input field and named is 'st' for a demo and on update of the algolia results jquery is using the .change function to append the value to the hidden input fields value. That way the form can be continued and sibmitted as i originally wanted and hoped for, The benefit here is that even if the user is to select a result from algoia drop down menu then continue with the form, If he or she decides they want to go back to the search field and change it, They can do before they submit the form or before any window.location is run, I even thought of using ajax or simply jquery $.post but its working ok the .change

Look forward to hearing your thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you want to redirect to an item page, the `typeahead:select` event gives you the selected option :
>
> ```
> $('#your-input')
>   .typeahead(/* ... */)
>   .on('typeahead:select', function (e, suggestion) {
>     window.location = suggestion.url;
>   });
> ```

from [Algolia redirect to search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173026/algolia-redirect-to-search-results/35180055#35180055)

---

You can access the selected object through the `suggestion` parameter. You could definitely use something like

```
window.location = 'YOUR_URL?id=' + suggestion.id + '&name=' + suggestion.name;
```

---

This assumes you're using `typeahead.js@0.11`.
`typeahead.js` being [unmaintained](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1320), Algolia recommends to use their own fork of `typeahead.js@0.10`, [`autocomplete.js`](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js).

Here are the different event names and handlers signatures depending on what library/version you're using:

- `typeahead.js@0.11`: `typeahead:select` -> `function($event, suggestion)`
- `typeahead.js@0.10`: `typeahead:selected` -> `function($event, suggestion, datasetName)`
- `autocomplete.js`: `autocomplete:selected` -> `function($event, suggestion, datasetName)`

Comment: Jerska, Excellent and well documented answer it is much appreciated and goes along way in helping people like myself resolve the issue they face. I have not had the chance to give it a shot at the moment but hopefully i understand enough to get it working as required. Again, Thanks for taking the time out to assist.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help. Don't hesitate to comment if when you start implementing you find out that something was missing from this answer.

Comment: Hi Jerska, I have only just managed to get round to testing the implementation, Seems to work perfectly although the only issue i face is that on select the code is using window.location and sending the user to the link, Unfortnetylu i need to keep them on the page for them to complete a secondary input field, I have updated my question with a working solution to what i faced, If you have any free time would you mind passing your thoughts on how im binding the id value to a hidden form field to enable to user to remain in the form process and submit as norma, Very Much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: That is definitely a viable option.

Comment: Im trying to stick with the ethos of:  Dont learn to code, You code to learn :)  Pointless trying to learn to code when the best way is to keep trying and trying everything and hopefully you will find a working way and then you learn from that, Refactoring your code as you better yourself :) Copying and pasting someones code is a quick and easy way of getting the problem solved, Writing it out yourself and making mistakes you overcome yourself gives you great rewards when you realise you have overcome the issue by using you own head a little bit. Thanks alot for your time, Its Been a pleasure.

Comment: You've got a nice approach to software development. Pleasure was mine. :)